# Redirect stdout using exec in subscript

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, command-line, sh

I have one main script which is started as an service.

I can't modify this main script, because it is often updated.
This main script starts a program, which echo any log to stdout.

So i can't see any log of this program.

But this main script calls at the beginning an hook-script, that I can modify.

If I redirect the stdout to a file in this hook-script, it works for that script, but not for the main script.

Is it possible to change the stdout for the whole process?

main (enigma2.sh):

```
# hook to execute scripts always before enigma2 start
if [ -x enigma2_pre_start.sh ]; then
  enigma2_pre_start.sh
fi

...

#this logs to stdout
/usr/bin/enigma2

...
```

hook (enigma2_pre_start.sh)

```
exec > /tmp/`date +"%s"`.log
exec 2> /tmp/`date +"%s"`_error.log
```

Edit:

Is it possible, to attach an tee (or similar) to the main process after it is started?
I know the main script is only run once. So i can get the process id with ps.

Comment: The `enigma2_pre_start.sh` is executed by new shell process so it cannot easily change stdout and stderr in its parent process. It would be possible if `enigma2_pre_start.sh` is sourced like `. enigma2_pre_start.sh` instead of executed. Is it possible to change it? And if it is not possible then is it possible to change the service startup script?

Comment: No I can either change the main script or the startup script, because if the system gets a update, both files will overwritten.

Comment: Then IMHO easy solution is not possible. Nevertheless you can still try some dirty trick in `enigma2_pre_start.sh`. For example you can find the line where is `enigma2_pre_start.sh` started in the `enigma2.sh` then change the line with `sed` so that script is sourced and rerun the `enigma2.sh`. When `enigma2_pre_start.sh` detects the line with its own start is already change then just redirect stdin and stdout and continue. When it finish then kill its parent to prevent doubled run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution based on the comment from "Zaboj Campula":

```
if /bin/grep -q "^[[:space:]]/usr/bin/enigma2_pre_start.sh$" /var/bin/enigma2.sh
then
        echo Unpatched > /tmp/enigma.sh
        /bin/sed -e 's/^\t\(\/usr\/bin\/enigma2_pre_start.sh\)$/\t\. \1/g' /var/bin/enigma2.sh -i
        pid=`/bin/ps -o ppid= $$` && /bin/kill $pid
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to source `enigma_pre_start.sh` instead of executing it, so that the `exec` commands run in the same process whose file handles you want to change.

```
if [ -x enigma2_pre_start.sh ]; then
    . enigma2_pre_start.sh
fi
```

Otherwise, you are redirecting the standard output and error of the process which executes the hook script, which exits as soon as the script completes.

Comment: I can't change the main script, because if the system receives an update, both files will be overwritten.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. You can't change redirect standard output of the current process from another process.